# Based Ps 84:11 Ps 34:10 Matt 7:11 Lk 11:8 does God give what is needed within good/healthy boundaries? (as opposed to fleshly wants/desires)

Tags: sin, blessings

Based on the following bible verses from both the Old and New Testament, I was trying to get a better understanding of God's characteristic when it comes to responding to human supplications.

Let's make note of the fact that Psalm 84:11, Psalm 34:10, Matthew 7:11, etc., emphasize that God gives "good" things to his followers, and also followers who ask him.

Furthermore, Luke 11:8 has more specifics because it emphasizes that even though the friend(who corresponds to God) will Not give the requester anything, the friend will give him what is needed( as opposed to what the requester's flesh wants/desires)

> Luke 11:8
>
> I tell you, even though he will not get up and give him
> anything because he is his friend, yet because of his [c]persistence
> he will get up and give him as much as he needs.

Therefore, Would it be correct to say that God will Only give what is needed within the boundaries of what is good/healthy As opposed to what our flesh wants/desires?

LOL, let me give a comical example.  Will God give you a relatively healthy Angel Food Cake which has relatively fewer calories than an Unhealthy Red Velvet Cake even though you requested that you wanted a Red Velvet Cake?

> Psalm 84:11 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 11 For the Lord God is a
> sun and shield; The Lord gives grace and glory;
> **No good thing does He withhold [a]from those who walk [b]uprightly.**

> Psalm 34:10 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 10 The young lions do
> lack and suffer hunger;
> **But they who seek the Lord shall not be in want of any good thing.**

> Luke 11:5-13
>
> 5 Then He said to them, “[d]Suppose one of you has a friend, and goes
> to him at midnight and says to him, ‘Friend, lend me three loaves; 6
> for a friend of mine has come to me from a journey, and I have nothing
> to set before him’; **7 and from inside he answers and says, ‘Do not
> bother me; the door has already been shut and my children [e]and I are
> in bed; I cannot get up and give you anything.’ 8 I tell you, even
> though he will not get up and give him anything because he is his
> friend, yet because of his [f]persistence he will get up and give him
> as much as he needs.**
>
> 9 “So I say to you, [g]ask, and it will be given to you; [h]seek, and
> you will find; [i]knock, and it will be opened to you. 10 For everyone
> who asks, receives; and he who seeks, finds; and to him who knocks, it
> will be opened. 11 Now [j]suppose one of you fathers is asked by his
> son for a [k]fish; he will not give him a snake instead of a fish,
> will he? 12 Or if he is asked for an egg, he will not give him a
> scorpion, will he? 13 If you then, being evil, know how to give good
> gifts to your children, how much more will your [l]heavenly Father
> give the Holy Spirit to those who ask Him?”

> Matthew 7:7-12
>
> 7 “[a]Ask, and it will be given to you; [b]seek, and you will find;
> [c]knock, and it will be opened to you. 8 For everyone who asks
> receives, and he who seeks finds, and to him who knocks it will be
> opened. 9 Or what man is there among you [d]who, when his son asks for
> a loaf, [e]will give him a stone? 10 Or [f]if he asks for a fish, he
> will not give him a snake, will he? **11 If you then, being evil, know
> how to give good gifts to your children, how much more will your
> Father who is in heaven give what is good to those who ask Him!**
>
> 12 “In everything, therefore, [g]treat people the same way you want
> [h]them to treat you, for this is the Law and the Prophets.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in its current format it is essentially self-answering, and is more about a theological harmonisation of various passages rather than an exegetical study of any in their own context.